# Ease the aggressive transition on images in spoilers

Tags: feature-request, design, images, spoilers

When a spoiler blockquote contains text, the text transitions in smoothly using a CSS transition. If it contains an image, the transition is abrupt.

[I've shared a brief animated gif of the transition as-is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG1NZ.gif)

If the CSS were changed from:

```
.spoiler:hover img {
    visibility: visible;
}
.spoiler img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

to:

```
.spoiler:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.spoiler img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

[The image transition would be much smoother](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEPfL.gif).

Live example:

> this is a test this is only a test
>  [image: placeholder image]

Comment: Took the liberty to add the live example here, so that we can see it happening.

Comment: Inline code too.

Comment: "Viewing this content requires Adobe Flash Player. You can download Adobe Flash Player from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/." Grr, why can't you just add a GIF? :P

Comment: @Doorknob, ...because I already had Jing, and I didn't have a tool for recording to GIF. I've updated the video links to GIFs.

Comment: @zzzzBov My comment was more tongue-in-cheek than anything, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Doorknob, I thought you were the one who downvoted me on this one, figured I'd take the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: @zzzzBov Ah, in fact I've already upvoted this. :)

Answer (score 4):

What, the annoyingly slow transition when showing spoilers is a feature, not a bug? Site designers and browser implementers, why are you deliberately making me suffer?

So, counter-feature-request: make the transition on text in spoilers instantaneous, like it's done for images.

Comment: I think a faster transition (2-300ms) would look a little nicer, but I don't think we should get rid of it altogether.

Comment: I think that having spoilers fade in slowly is a useful feature - it gives you a (short) window of time in which you can realize that you have accidentally moused over something you didn't mean to mouse over, allowing you to avert your eyes or move your mouse elsewhere or something.

Comment: I am with Gilles on this - slow transitions just make everything slower and more annoying on the internet. Please make it immediate.